# Nullable Types and Operators

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I was reading about **Nullable Types and Operators** from **Wrox** and came across the following statement:

> When comparing nullable types, if only one of the operands is null, the comparison will always equate to false. This means that you cannot assume a condition is true just because its opposite is false.

Now, I get what the first statement means but didn't get the second statement.
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Where were you reading this?  was it somewhere online where we can go look at it?

Comment: You can most certainly generally assume that if a condition's opposite is false it's true - that's what opposite means.

Comment: No, it's from book Professional C# 4 and .NET 4

Comment: @R0MANARMY you can't find one because it's a basic axiom of logic. "A or not A" always holds in the logic we commonly use. Note that this is not the same as `A == A` (which doesn't hold in programming in some cases).

Comment: It might be talking about how logical and and logical or work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears like the quote is saying that any comparison at all with a null type will return null, regardless of the operand.

So something like `(null != 5)`  Would return `false`, where `(null == 5)` would also return false.

---

Now, the funny thing is, that when I ran a program, `null != 5` returned **true**, so while I can't verify that statement for c# 2.0, it's definitely not true anymore in c# 4.0 +

This is the sample code I've used:

```
int? a = null;

int? b = 5;

if (a != b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A != B");
}
if (a == b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A == B");
}
```

This is the output

> A != B
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 3):

That quote is wrong, MSDN is the official source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one
>   of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons
>   evaluate to false **except for != (not equal)**.

The second statement simply means that a comparison and its opposite may be both false, eg a>=b and a<b are both false.

Here's the logic. Null kind of means an unknown value. Now try to calculate 5<null, 5<=null, 5==null, 5>=null, 5>null. You can't exactly calculate any of these, they are not true or false either, they are unknown, but false makes a bit more sense than true. The exception is 5!=null. An exact number is not unknown, so it makes a bit more sense that it's true than false. So ==  and != are the opposite of each other, it's the easy case, but you can't say that for greater-less comparisons. It was a design choice when they made C#/.NET.

SQL on the other hand got it quite right I think with 3-valued-logic, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29